# Does To_Date evaluate a string to a date of midnight if timestamp is not specified in the string?

Tags: sql, oracle, date, datetime

When I use `To_Date` to convert a string to a date, does Oracle default the date to the midnight of the day? That is, `To_Date('08/26/2022','MM/DD/YYYY')` is valued at 08/26/2022 00:00:00?

I am asking because when I use this to restrict the dates I am querying, I cannot get a row with datetime 08/26/2022 06:23:23 to return. I am guessing this is because 08/26/2022 06:23:23 is after 08/26/2022 00:00:00 and `To_Date('08/26/2022','MM/DD/YYYY')` is just 08/26/2022 00:00:00. Am I correct?

I just want to validate my suspicion/theory. I do know that if I use `TRUNC(date_field) = To_Date ('08/26/2022','MM/DD/YYYY')`, the row of 08/26/2022 06:23:23 returns. So I know that's my solution. But it will be good to know how the language/Oracle behaves.

Comment: This can be determined by actually trying it.

Comment: @MatBailie It is not very helpful to say this can be determined by trying without providing an explanation of how to do that. I understand you are way more knowledgeable/experienced in SQL and my question is basic to you, but I'd appreciate if you can accommodate someone who does not use SQL often and have no experienced friend/co-worker to turn to. Can you also explain why this is a duplicate or provide an actual question that is similar to mine? I searched everywhere and did not find a similar question. The question you or others provided is not the same.

Answer (score 2):

This is simple to test for yourself, even if your client just shows you the result without a time by default:

```
select to_date('08/26/2022','MM/DD/YYYY') from dual
```

| TO_DATE('08/26/2022','MM/DD/YYYY') |
| --- |
| 26-AUG-22 |

```
select to_char(to_date('08/26/2022','MM/DD/YYYY'), 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from dual
```

| TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('08/26/2022','MM/DD/YYYY'),'MM/DD/YYYYHH24:MI:SS') |
| --- |
| 08/26/2022 00:00:00 |

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'
```

```
select to_date('08/26/2022','MM/DD/YYYY') from dual
```

| TO_DATE('08/26/2022','MM/DD/YYYY') |
| --- |
| 2022-08-26 00:00:00 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/gn029E8R)

The behaviour is documented, though you have to search for it a bit (or know where to look); from [the Database Globalization Support Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/nlspg/datetime-data-types-and-time-zone-support.html#GUID-4D95F6B2-8F28-458A-820D-6C05F848CA23):

> If you specify a date value without a time component, then the default time is midnight. If you specify a date value without a date, then the default date is the first day of the current month.

---

You also said:

> I do know that if I use TRUNC(date_field) = To_Date ('08/26/2022','MM/DD/YYYY'), the row of 08/26/2022 06:23:23 returns. So I know that's my solution.

That is a solution, but it's generally better to apply a date range to your column, rather than applying a function like `trunc()` to it, because that will stop a normal index on the column being used. Every value in the table will have to be truncated to then be compared with your fixed midnight-values date.

Instead you can do:

```
where date_field >= to_date('08/26/2022','MM/DD/YYYY')
and date_field < to_date('08/27/2022','MM/DD/YYYY')
```

or with date literals:

```
where date_field >= date '2022-08-26'
and date_field < date '2022-08-27'
```

either which will find all values at or after midnight on the 26th and before midnight on the 27th - which is all possible times on the 26th.

Comment: Using `x >= a_date AND x < a_date_plus_one` is an extremely valuable lesson to learn.

Comment: Thank you for providing the resources and showing me the way to check this myself. Is it better to always avoid using Trunc()? I also use Trunc() when I need to compare two datetime fields of two tables. It seems that Trunc() is the best way to avoid same date and different timestamp being treated as different date.

Comment: It might be suitable then, but it depends on the circumstances. It might only make sense to trunc one of the dates and compare to a range of the other - it depends, on the data, volumes, indexes etc. If there is a more efficient way then you should use that, but it can take some experimentation and understanding of the data, or looking at the execution plans. I would generally use trunc for things like aggregating data across a day (e.g. `group by trunc(date_field)` but there are always exceptions.

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much for the guidance. (I know I am not supposed to write a comment just to show appreciation so hopefully you see the comment before it is deleted by someone.) -- I will also make sure to save your answers before someone deletes my entire post.